# Напрямую через html страницу выводит изображение, но как только выгружаю его ссылку через бд, странным образом перестает выводится

Tags: php, html

Пример при котором не выводится изображение через бд. В чем может быть проблема? Буду благодарен за ответ

```
<img src="<?php echo"{$result['img']}";?>">
```

Comment: <img src="<?php echo"{$result['img']}";?>">

Comment: Что это за кавычки и скобки при выводе? `var_dump($result);` выложите сюда

Comment: в кавычки помещается адрес изображения тега img

Comment: $result['img'] что содержит покажите

Comment: https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg   - это содержится в строке                                                                                                           
     Попробовал сделать тег в самой бд, даже так не выводится, работает через html, база данных рабочая, ибо это один из столбцов

Comment: `<img src="<?= $result['img']; ?>">`

Comment: При этом варианте исчезли иконки изображений(под иконками я имею ввиду ошибку вывода )

Comment: Догадываюсь.. Вообще, что это за картинка? Как она там берётся?

Comment: `<img src="<?= 'https://' . $result['img']; ?>">`

Comment: там хранится вот это https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg, думаю https лишнее. Это некая доска объявлений, я сам отправляю url ссылку из формы, она грузится в бд, а оттуда на страницу.Так что принципиально чтобы изображение не было html файлом

Comment: Значит ищите проблему в логике

Comment: спасибо за помощь, проблему решили

Answer (score 0):

Если файл хранится на вашем сервере и в БД ссылка хранится без слеша (`/`) в начале, то она может генерироваться некорректно, типа `mysite.comimage.jpg`.

Т.е. в местах, где выводятся такие ссылки моно добавить слеш в шаблоне:

```
<img src="/<?= $result['img']; ?>">
```

Если же в шаблон приходит объект, то можно и так:

```
<img src="/<?= $result->img; ?>">
```

`;` в конце не обязательна.

Comment: Вот эта ссылка, копирую я ее из бд, напрямую все работает : https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg

Comment: а как только помещаю в это: <img src="<?php echo"{$result['img']}";?>">,перестает работать

Comment: А $result в каком виде приходит?

Comment: И зачем там фигурные скобки?

Comment: Упростил код в ответе.

Comment: Без фигурных скобок выдает ошибку, резалт это текстовая ячейка, если вы про это. При добавлении слеша есть продвижение, появилась иконка незагруженного изображения, раньше и ее не было. Я могу предоставить какую нибудь информацию которая поможет найти решение?

Comment: Сделайте var_dump($result['img'])

Comment: <img src="/<?= $result->img; ?>"> этот вариант не хочет работать

Comment: Если у вас в БД ссылка хранится без указания протокола, то будет генерироваться некорректная, как в моём ответе. Т.е. в вашем случае: `http://mysite.cominteractive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg`

Comment: https:// - вы же про это? Если так, то в бд протокол есть, не нашел как вставить сюда скриншот, а при копировании ссылки в чат показывает без https

Comment: Сделайте так и покажите тут, что вывалит на странице вместо картинки
`<img src=""><?= var_dump($result) ?>`

Comment: array(8) { [0]=> string(3) "132" ["ID"]=> string(3) "132" [1]=> string(0) "" ["age"]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" ["animal"]=> string(0) "" [3]=> string(0) "" ["contact"]=> string(0) "" } года(лет)

Comment: У вас какой-то очень странный массив. Явно сами собираете, не из модели. В любом случае, как сами видите, в нём нет элемента с ключом `img`, который вы пытаетесь вывести таким образом $result['img']. Поэтому у вас там и пусто.

Comment: Спасибо, за помощь, после ваших слов начал все перепроверять, массив и правда странный, теперь заработало. Извиняюсь что потратил время. Именно эту часть сам писал, но у меня обычно ничего не работает, откуда бы не брал.